# How can I access the props for a nested component in React?

Tags: reactjs

I want to pass props to my nested component but the problem here is the inner card component that is not showing the data passed to it neither the Inner text props nor the inner `pct` props.

This is my index.js

```
const tst = () => {
    return (
        <div className="d-flex">
            <Card text={"occupied"} pct={75}  width={250}/>
            <Card width={370}>
                <InnerCard2 Innertext={"Compeleted"} InnerPct={25}/>
                <InnerCard2 Innertext={"WIP"} InnerPct={50}/>
                <InnerCard2 Innertext={"Upcoming"} InnerPct={25}/>
            </Card>
            
}
```

This is my card component:

```
import React from 'react';
import InnerCard2 from './InnerCard2';
class Card extends React.Component {

    render() { 
        var {text="", pct=0, } = this.props
        const style = {
            width: this.props.width + 'px',
            marginRight: '10px'
        }
        return (
           
            <div className="white-box v-align ht-100" style={style}>
                <div className="flex-one"></div>
                <div className="wd-80">
                    <div className="fs-xl fw-bold" style={{ color: '#142654' }}>{pct} %</div>
                    <div className="small-text">{text}</div>
                </div>
               
            </div>
            
            );
    }
}
 
export default Card;
```

This is my inner card component:

```
import React from 'react';
class InnerCard2 extends React.Component {

    render() { 
        var {InnerText="", InnerPct=0} = this.props
        
        return (
           
            <div className="wd-80">
                <div className="fs-xl fw-bold" style={{ color: '#669900' }}>{InnerPct}%</div>
                <div className="small-text">{InnerText}</div>
            </div>
            
            );
    }
}
 
export default InnerCard2;
```

Answer (score 1):

At a glance I'm seeing two problems:

First, `InnerCard` is expecting a property called `InnerText` but you're passing it a property called `Innertext`.  Casing matters.  Either change the name of the property in the component or change the name of the property being passed to the component.

Second, the `Card` component is ignoring its `children` property, so it doesn't render them.  By convention any child components wrapped by a component are passed to it as a prop called `children`.  Add `children` to the prop deconstruction:

```
var {text="", pct=0, children } = this.props
```

And display the children wherever you want to in the rendering.  For example:

```
<div>
  {children}
</div>
```

Comment: where should i define the children property i have destructured the props in both the components

Comment: @AbhishekRoy: Do you mean where should you render it?  Wherever you like in your JSX.

Comment: I am not understanding how should I get the data that I have passed in index.jsx under card component in innercard2 component

Comment: @AbhishekRoy: You're already passing values to your `InnerCard2` component.  One of them just has a typo.  Pass props to a component like this: `<InnerCard2 InnerText={"Compeleted"} InnerPct={25} />` and then within the component you can get those values from `props` like this: `var { InnerText="", InnerPct=0 } = this.props;`  You're already doing these parts correctly, you just need to make sure the casing matches on the names.  The other issue in the code had nothing to do with passing props, you simply weren't rendering the component's children.

Comment: I fixed that error but still the props of innercard2 is not showing in the ui

Comment: @AbhishekRoy: What changes did you make?  Show your updated code.